# Which SQLite methods to make Synchronized?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-file

My database is being backed up by FileBackupHelper and the guide says to synchronize this activity with db file access in my app. I'm trying to figure out where this is necessary.

I could synchronize certain functions or all access. I'm considering three options:

1) Synchronize only database edits (writes)

```
synchronized(MyLocks.DBLock){
    db.insert(MY_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    db.update(MY_TABLE, contentValues, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{str})});
}
```

2) Also synchronize reading the database in my adapter.

```
synchronized(MyLocks.DBLock){
    db.insert(MY_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    db.update(MY_TABLE, contentValues, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{str})});

    Cursor c = db.query(true, MY_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_EC}, KEY_ID + "=" + id, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null && c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    } else{
        if(c != null)
            c.close();
        return null;
    }
    Double d = Double.valueOf(c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EC)));
    c.close();
}
```

3) Synchronize everything from the moment an activity opens my database adapter.

```
// in an activity

DBAdapter dba = new DBAdapter(context);
synchronized(MyLocks.DBLock){
    dba.open();
    dba.doDatabaseOperation();
    dba.close();
}
```

Which of these is approaches is necessary?